# How to remove underscores from a text in Quanteda Tokens in R

Tags: r, regex, quanteda

**EDIT** See EDIT below

I'm trying to convert a corpus object to tokens using R and Quanteda. Using the options in token() I cannot seem to remove the underscores in some words/characters. When I try using stri_replace_all_regex() the characters completely disappear.

The following code gives the below output

CODE

```
dirty_corpus <- corpus(textdata)

toks <- dirty_corpus %>%
  stringi::stri_replace_all_regex("\'[a-z]*", "") %>%
  tokens(what = "word", remove_punct = TRUE, preserve_tags = FALSE, remove_numbers = TRUE, remove_separators = TRUE,
         remove_url = TRUE, split_hyphens = TRUE, remove_symbols = TRUE, split_tags = TRUE, verbose = TRUE) %>%
  tokens_remove(pattern = phrase(english_stopwords), valuetype = 'fixed') %>%
  tokens_wordstem() %>%
  tokens_tolower()
```

Output:

`text6 : [1] "ys"   "s_"   "_t"   "_s"   "sw"   "lnk"  "smn"  "pstd" "dwn"  "blw"  [11] "srri"`

I want the following output:

`text6 : [1] "ys"   "s"   "t"   "s"   "sw"   "lnk"  "smn"  "pstd" "dwn"  "blw"  [11] "srri"`

When I chain:

```
stringi::stri_replace_all_regex("_", "") %>%
```

resuling into the code:

```
dirty_corpus <- corpus(textdata)

toks <- dirty_corpus %>%
  stringi::stri_replace_all_regex("\'[a-z]*", "") %>%
  stringi::stri_replace_all_regex("_", "") %>%
  tokens(what = "word", remove_punct = TRUE, preserve_tags = FALSE, remove_numbers = TRUE, remove_separators = TRUE,
         remove_url = TRUE, split_hyphens = TRUE, remove_symbols = TRUE, split_tags = TRUE, verbose = TRUE) %>%
  tokens_remove(pattern = phrase(english_stopwords), valuetype = 'fixed') %>%
  tokens_wordstem() %>%
  tokens_tolower()
```

The output becomes the following:

`text6 : [1] "ys"   "sw"   "lnk"  "smn"  "pstd" "dwn"  "blw"  "srri"`

Making the characters previously contain the underscore disappear.

How can I obtain the result I intend?

**EDIT**
In hindsight everything was performing exactly as planned! Since I didn't write all of the code myself I did not realize the characters being removed were in the stopwords list, hence they were being removed! Stupid!

Comment: What is the outpu if you just run the first 3 lines? Ie. `dirty_corpus %>%
  stringi::stri_replace_all_regex("\'[a-z]*", "") %>%
  stringi::stri_replace_all_regex("_", "")`
My guess is that the 't's and 's's are getting removed by the next 3 lines.

Comment: Hey @NicolásVelásquez thx for your answer. Well I think it's not the case because if I run the first example after that code they are still in there. After the regex calls nothing is changed in the other samples!

Comment: Hello @DartLazer, to better help you could you please let us know which packages are you using? Also, a sample of the dirty_corpus might be helpful.

Comment: @NicolásVelásquez Thank you once again for your comment! After debugging I came to the conclusion that your first Guess was right! These characters were in my stopwords list hence they were being removed! My apologies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In hindsight everything was performing exactly as planned! Since I didn't write all of the code myself I did not realize the characters being removed were in the stopwords list, hence they were being removed! Stupid!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `types()` and `tokens_replace()` to modify your tokens using **stringi** functions.

```r
require(quanteda)
txt <- "_t ys s_ _t _s sw lnk _s"
toks <- tokens(txt)
print(toks)
#> Tokens consisting of 1 document.
#> text1 :
#> [1] "_t"  "ys"  "s_"  "_t"  "_s"  "sw"  "lnk" "_s"
toks_rep <- tokens_replace(toks, 
                           pattern = types(toks), 
                           replacement = stringi::stri_replace_all_fixed(types(toks), "_", ""),
                           valuetype = "fixed")
print(toks_rep)
#> Tokens consisting of 1 document.
#> text1 :
#> [1] "t"   "ys"  "s"   "t"   "s"   "sw"  "lnk" "s"
```

You can also use `tokens_split(toks, "_")` if you have the underscores in-between like "y_s".

Comment: Thank you very much! In the end the problem was of my own doing! I accidentally removed these characters using the remove stopwords function. They were included in the stopwords list!